# Java Singly-Linked-List Recreation

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

So for an assignment I need to basically make a singly linked list, with 2 methods, `add(x)` This adds a new node to the end of the list, and a `deleteMin()` that removes from the end of the list

At the bottom is the code I made. I keep on getting the error `java.lang.NullPointerException` at line 66

Inside the add(x) method at `head.next = u;`

I have tried to change the code a few times to fix this error and nothing seems to work.

```
package assignment1;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SLL {
    private int item;
    private SLL next;

    SLL(int x, SLL y){
        item = x;
        next = y;
    }

    public static SLL head;
    public static SLL tail;
    public static int n;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean x = true;
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("A = add element, R = remove element, L = to list items inside Singly-Linked-List, Q = to stop session");
        while (x == true) {
            String user = user_input.next();
            String userLow = user.toLowerCase();
            switch (userLow) {
                case "a":
                    System.out.println("Add an integer");
                    int a;
                    try {
                        a = user_input.nextInt();
                    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                        System.out.println("Incorect input, please input an integer.");
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                    add(a);
                    break;
                case "r":
                    deleteMin();
                    break;
                case "l":
                    //list();
                    break;
                case "q":
                    x = false;
                    break;
                case "help":
                    System.out.println("A = add element, R = remove element, L = to list items inside queue, Q = to stop session");
                    break;
                case "?":
                    System.out.println("A = add element, R = remove element, L = to list items inside queue, Q = to stop session");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Not a recognized command: try 'help' or '?' for a list of commands");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void add(int x){
        SLL u = new SLL(x, head);
        if (n == 0) {
            head.next = u; // <<<------------
            head.next.next = tail;
        } else {
            SLL current = head;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = u;
            current.next.next = tail;
        }
        n++;
    }
    public static void deleteMin(){
        if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println("No elements inside list");
        } else if (n == 1) {
            head.next = null;
            tail.next = null;
            n--;
        } else {
            head.next = head.next.next;
            head.next.next = null;
            n--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `head` yet, but try to access it's `next` attribute. This leads to a `NullPointerException`, since `head` is `null` at that time.

You need to initialize your `head` variable with sth. like `head = new SSL(item, next)` before you try to access it's values.

As you're setting the next attribute in that line and your `SSL` constructor sets that, too, you may want to replace  `head.next = u;` with `head = new SSL(x, u);`.

The way you're doing it, the next line will also result in a `NullPointerException`, since when you assign `head.next.next = tail;` the `head.next` is `null`. This comes from `head` being `null` when you hand it to the constructor in `SLL u = new SLL(x, head);`.
Also this line may be ineffective anyway, because at this moment `tail` is `null` too. So you basically do `head.next.next = null;`.

Comment: don't forget to say very unorganized as well

Comment: @KickButtowski I actually typed something like that seconds ago, since `u` seems to be a little bit displaced, but throw it away then.